# How to solve $f''(x)=-\frac{C}{f^2(x)}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$f''(x)=-\frac{C}{f^2(x)} (C\in\mathbf{R}, C>0)$$

Reference were also enough.

Comment: Multiply by $2f'$ and observe that $f'^2-2C/f$ is a first integral. Finally, note that the corresponding 1st order ODE is separable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying by $f'(x)$ and using $d/dx\,(f'(x)^2)=2f'(x)f''(x)$ gives
\begin{align}
f'(x)\cdot f''(x) &= -\frac{C\,f'(x)}{f(x)^2} \\
\frac{1}{2}f'(x)^2&= \frac{C}{f(x)} + D \\
f'(x) &= \sqrt{\frac{2C}{f(x)} + 2D} \\
1 &= \frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{\frac{2C}{f(x)} + 2D}} \\
&= f'(x)\frac{\sqrt{f(x)}}{\sqrt{2C + 2Df(x)}}.
\end{align}
If you can integrate both sides of the last equation and solve for $f(x)$, you'll be done.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'=p \rightarrow y''=\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}.\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}.p$$
So
$$\frac{dp}{dy}.p=-\frac{C}{y^2}$$
or
$$pdp=-C\frac{dy}{y^2}$$
Therefore $$\frac{p^2}{2}=\frac{C}{y}+C'$$
and proceed.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand. Could you use my notation, or give a reference about yours?

Comment: @ peter: see this pdf file, page 4. http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-2nd%20order%20ODE%20pt1.pdf